# Child div removed after appending HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a panel `interest` that opens and closes on click.  When it opens the first time (on the first click), the `#interest-close` button is visible and closes the panel on click as it should.  However, the second time panel is opened,  the `#interest-close` button is no longer visible.  It is removed from the DOM.

I have tried changing `#interest-close` position to absolute and `#interest` to relative, but that does not work.

I think it has to do with the fact that I am changing the display to `block`  and then appending HTML with `appendTo` but I do not understand why the panel works correctly the first time it opens, but on the second the close button disappears and therefore the panel cannot be closed again.

What might be causing this problem?

#### CSS:

```
#interest {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88);
  color: #fff;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#interest-close {
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 19px;
  content: url('./back-button.svg');
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 13px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#interest-close:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id='interest'>
  <div id = 'interest-close'></div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$("#interest-close").on('click', function() {

          $("#interest").attr("style", "display:none");

});



item.addEventListener('click', function(){

//fill panel with program info
    interest = document.getElementById("interest")


    interest.style.display = "block";

    $('<div style ="font-size:35px; margin-left:10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 25px">' + prop.title + '</div>' +
            '<div style ="font-size:35px; margin-left:10px; margin-top: 25px;">' + "info info info info" + '</div>').appendTo("#interest");

 });
```

**Note:** when using `innerHTML =` instead of `appendTo()`, the `interest-close` button does not appear at all.

Comment: What's an `item` ?

Comment: Hard to say for sure what's causing your problem without the full example. Open your browser's inspector (`ctrl+shift+i`) and examine the DOM to see what happened to your button.

Comment: That is a different DOM element, but the problem is not with that.   The problem is what is inside `interest`.  For example, when I use `innerHTML` instead of `appendTo()`, the `interest-close` button is completely invisible, even on first click.  I'll add that as a note.

Comment: The button literally disappears and is no longer visible in the DOM when the panel is opened the second time.

Comment: It is not clear how you open the panel again. Currently the shown code only hides it and that's all.

Comment: `var item = document.createElement('a');` `item` is just a block in a list of elements.  The problem is not with opening the panel itself , but with what is inside the panel (specifically the close button).  I cannot include the entire block of code because it is too lengthy

Comment: From your question, it looks like panel is what represented by '#interest'. (Your first line I have a panel interest that opens and closes on click) However upon clicking the close button, you are setting the display of $('#interest') to none. So how are you opening the panel again? Or does panel mean something else?

Comment: with  `interest.style.display = "block";`  when clicking on `item`.

Comment: that's correct `#interest` is the panel

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle showing the issue?

Comment: InnerHTML would clear all of the HTML in `#interest` and would remove the close button, so that behavior is expected. Use InnerHTML, but prepend your close button HTML first so that it shows up every time.

Comment: That makes sense. How would you prepend it?

Comment: When you set `innerHTML = "<div id='interest-close'></div><!--Plus all your other super cool code.-->"`

Comment: That is because the listener is detached each time you remove it from the DOM. I'll post an answer with more code that might be better than innerHTML

Comment: I see. Thanks for the observation

Comment: Try that answer. You can just change your listener and maintain innerHTML setting, like at the bottom of the post, or change the rest of the code. Up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain the close button in the DOM, and not remove it so that the listener gets detached. The thing I'd recommend doing is removing all content except the close button each time.

```
$("#interest-close").on('click', function() {
    $("#interest").attr("style", "display:none");
});

item.addEventListener('click', function(){
    interest = document.getElementById("interest")
    interest.style.display = "block";

    $("#interest").children().not('#interest-close').remove();
    $("#interest-close").after('<div style ="font-size:35px; margin-left:10px; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 25px">' + prop.title + '</div>' +
'<div style ="font-size:35px; margin-left:10px; margin-top: 25px;">' + "info info info info" + '</div>')
});
```

I'm not certain this will work. It would be better if we had a fiddle to play with. The line I'm concerned about is when we remove the content from `#interest`.

The other thing we can do is attach the listener to the document, and replace the innerHTML every time because the event will fire on the document, then to the selector. In this case, replacing the innerHTML, like we discussed in the comments, won't break the listener.

```
$(document).on('click', "#interest-close", function() {
    $("#interest").attr("style", "display:none");
})
```